# Error regarding subprocess install in python

Tags: python, subprocess, openpyxl, sys

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', openpyxl])
import openpyxl
```

I am trying to install `openpyxl` using `subprocess` and `sys` module, but get `error not defined openpyxl`.
How might I resolve this?

Comment: You need quotes around openpyxl, unless it is a variable defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I used `subprocess.Popen` as launcher and added double-quotes around `openpyxl`:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "openpyxl"])

import openpyxl
```

Comment: gettion error No matching distribution found for openpyxl

Comment: This is because one of your packages is outdated but is not related to the initial error reported. You can try to upgrade pip before, but without guarantee: pip install --upgrade pip in command line. Or with subprocess, adding before installing openpyxl: subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"])